# How to position a div based on the position of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I saw it on a site called Medium.com and I want to make it on my website too.

**When the shared post is at the top of the page =**

[first.image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQhCf.png)

**When the shared post is at the bottom of the page =**

[second.image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXbgj.png)

I will make this in angular. I hope I have made my request clear.

Comment: Could you provide some code for what you have tried?

Comment: @BernardBorg Sorry, i haven't tried anything yet. But if you know any code examples like this, can you show it to me?

Comment: Use Angular Material Menu. So you do not need to write it yourself.  https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Angular Material Menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) which looks similar and handels the positioning of the dropdown and is supported by the Angular Material Team.

```
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voice mail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```